# Serve common static files with App Engine and Flask

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, static-files, app.yaml

I'm writing a service with 2 blueprints(auth & business), each of the blueprint is located in its own package, I need to share some images, scripts and styles accross the Blueprints.

When placing the `flash.js` and `favicon.png` in the appropriate folder(***styles, images or scripts***) in the root static folder is not being fetched when deployed to GCP, while running the app locally the files are being routed properly.

What is the appropriate way to share common static files across blueprints when deploying to GAE?

The Blueprints are defined as follow:

```
auth_bp = Blueprint(
    'auth',
    __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static',
    static_url_path='/auth/static/'
)
business_bp = Blueprint(
    'business',
    __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static',
    static_url_path='/business/static/'
)
```

The package structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── blueprint.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── images
│   │   │   │   └── favicon.png
│   │   │   ├── scripts
│   │   │   │   ├── captcha.js
│   │   │   │   ├── login.js
│   │   │   │   └── reset-password.js
│   │   │   └── styles
│   │   │       └── main.css
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── base-auth.html
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── reset-password.html
│   │   │   └── reset-request.html
│   │   └── utilities.py
│   ├── business
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── blueprint.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   └── templates
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── system_user.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── scripts
│   │   │   └── flash.js
│   │   └── styles
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── _macros.html
│   └── utilities
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── utilities.py
├── app.yaml
├── deployer.sh
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python311
default_expiration: "2h"

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
```

This would be a sample on how I want to use the shared files:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/favicon.png') }}" />
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/favicon.png') }}" type="image/png" />
  <script src="{{ url_for('auth.static', filename = 'scripts/captcha.js') }}" defer></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'scripts/flash.js') }}" defer></script>
  ...
</head>
```

The `favicon.png` I want to use it accross the application, along with the `flash.js` while the `captcha.js`, I want it only on the `auth` Blueprint.

Locally, this setup is working fine, is when I deploy to GAE that doesn't work anymore as expected(the *shared* static files return 404 and the endpoint is not created), so my guess is that my `app.yaml` needs fine tuning, but can't find a resource to lead my in the right direction.

***UPDATE I***

I removed the `static` declaration from `app.yaml` and at least the script `flash.js` worked as expected when deploying.

However I tested the `auth` blueprint and `current_app` `static_folder` and `static_url_path` when deployed with and without the `static` declaration on the `app.yaml` file and in both cases is the same, but the resources are missing when the declaration is on de yaml file.

In both cases only the `auth/static` is available on the developer console under `sources` in Chrome.

`app.yaml` with the `static` declaration
[image: Static handler in yaml]

`app.yaml` without the `static` declaration
[image: No Static handler declaration in yaml]

To move on, removed the files and hosted them on a Storage Bucket.

***UPDATE II***

When checking the source in the rendered webpage the path created by `url_for` seemed correct `static/scripts/flash.js` for the scripts and `static/images/favicon.png` for the images, but the favicon was nowhere to be found(404) while the script was available only when I removed the `static` declaration from the `app.yaml`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the url or path you use for one of the 'shared' images?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Done, forgot to add that...

Comment: @GuanacoDevs, can you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=python#serving_from_your_application) if there are errors in the directory path and/or declared `handlers` and its values?

Comment: Where is the file for the sample code you have located? Is it within the ```business``` or ```auth``` folders? In addition, open the page in your browser, view source and include the urls that your code resolved to for both the static file that gives 404 and the one that works. You can mask your domain names; I want to see the full path to the static files cos that will help to craft the entry for your ```app.yaml```.

Comment: @NoCommandLine `business`and `auth` are blueprints, `app/static` is the folder where I want to place common files that I could use in any blueprint on the app. The setup in the question works fine while working locally, however when I deploy to GAE, the links are properly generated but the resources are nowhere to be found(404). If I remove the `static` declaration from `app.yaml` the `flash.js` script works when deployed but not the `favicon.png` located on `static/images`.

Comment: @NoCommandLine in order to move on, I removed the static folder that I wanted to use for `global` static files and hosted them on a Storage Bucket.

Comment: I get the work around you implemented. However, I'm not clear on the extra information you added. What I wanted was the full path that shows up (in your browser) for any of the files you stored in the common static folder. e.g. if it shows up as ```/srv/app/static```, then that is what you need to have in your ```app.yaml``` file. Remember, your ```app.yaml``` file is telling Google - when you see a path ```/srv/app/static```, go and look for the file in the folder called ```static``` in my root directory. The path in your ```app.yaml``` MUST MATCH the path that shows up in your html page

Comment: @NoCommandLine the `/srv/app` segments are created by  GAE when building the image and with or without the `static` declaration both they are the same, I even change the name from `static` to `public` to see if there was any difference, but still the same I even moved the files from outside `app` inside and refactor, yet after refactoring the same, the files are not available. I really like to understand what is the proper way but have been stuck on it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dummy project to try to reproduce your issue.

1. Below is the project folder structure (project is called `common_static_files` and I have 2 sub apps called `app_1` and `app_2`

   [image]
2. The blueprint definition in `app_1`

   ```
   app_1_handlers = Blueprint("app_1_handlers", __name__, 
       template_folder="templates",
       static_folder='static',
       static_url_path='/app_1/static/')
   ```
3. The contents of `app.yaml` file

   ```
   # This handles static files under the app_2 folder
   - url: /app_2/static
     static_dir: common_static_files/app_2/static

   # This handles static files under the app_1 folder
   - url: /app_1/static
     static_dir: common_static_files/app_1/static

   # This handles static files in the common static folder (in the root of the project)
   - url: /static
     static_dir: common_static_files/static/
   ```
4. The contents of `app_1.htm` under the templates folder in `app_1` folder

   **Notice** how the package name is used for the static handler for app_1

   ```
   <head>
       <link href="{{ url_for('app_1_handlers.static', filename = 'css/app_1.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>

   <body >

       <div style="font-size: 3em; margin-top: 20px;">{{message}} </div>
       <div style="margin-top:20px;">
           <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'images/question.png') }}" />
       </div>

   </body>
   ```
5. The output when the page is loaded

   a) The css file with a black background and white text color is under `app_1 > static > css > app_1.css`

   b) The image (screenshot of the stackoverflow question) is in the common static folder

   [image]
6. 